# Nest E Y1 cable cutting power to thermostat

Tags: hvac

[image][image: Thjis is where tech disconnected cables from thermostat (red and white) and connected directly to this Becket EniSys][image][image][image][image][image][image]I am trying to connect a Nest E thermorstat on my HVAC unit that runs heat and AC.
 i have yellow-y1, G-green,White-w, red- R. When y1 is connected i get the error No power to R, i see the C wire on the cable, i connected the blue to C and make sure is connected to C on the furnace and AC but i get no power. I have to disconnect C and Y1 for heat to turn on but no AC. temperature in Connecticut now is 60F its not to cold to get those errors. Should i just buy a 24 AC wall transformer and connect it to the R and C cables to the thermostat? Nest tech support tells me C wire is not grounded, but i see it grounded on the board.

Comment: Can you include a wiring diagram for your HVAC unit? And/or a picture of the control board? What were the wires connected to on your old thermostat?

Comment: Hi,. The connection to the old thermostat were the following.  y to yellow, g to green, w to white, red to rc.  

I can get you a picture of the diagram and HVAC control unit as soon I get home.

Comment: Also take and post a picture of the actual connections at the furnace end of the thermostat cable.

Comment: sorry guys, i got the pictures, but where do i upload them? cant see a button for uploading

Comment: @Allan -- it's the button that looks like a framed picture, next to the two braces button

Comment: Cable with back tape is going to the thermostat, the other one with the white and green rolled up goes to the AC Coil outside.

Comment: If you disconnect the cable going to the outside AC coil (just pull the yellow wire from that cable off the Y terminal on the board), does the thermostat still throw that error?

Comment: Tried with yellow cable off and same problem

Comment: you can see on the first two pictures from top to bottom theres nothing connected on the W and the red connected on the R is for the condenser.  they got disconnected and connected to the EniSys 120V

Answer (score 1):

You will need a wire going from the C on the thermostat to the C on the furnace, 5 wires total. R to R, W to W, Y to Y, G to G and C to C.  At the furnace there will also be a second wire on the Y and C and they will go to your condensing unit.  I can not tell from your pictures but it looks like the blue wire on the furnace C is probably going to the condensing unit.

Comment: There are two blue wires connected to the board.  One from thermostat and one to condense unit.

Comment: I don’t see any blue wire at either one of the thermostats. I see green, red, yellow and white. Your old thermostat looks like it was battery powered since there is no C terminal.

Comment: When I connect the blue wire in the thermostat I get a power issue on the nest e.  I was told by nest tech support to disconnect it because it's not grounded.  We had to take off the yellow and blue to make it work, but only heat is working.

Comment: Now I just noticed the white cable and red cable are not connected to the R and W on the board.  I am posting a new picture

Comment: Now I remember...  I had my furnace maintenance two months ago, the tech saw a problem with the relay so he disconnected the red and white and connected them directly, maybe that's causing the problem?  I am posting a picture now..

Comment: It is still hard to see where the wires are going in the photos. It is possible that a part was bad and the technician rewired it to make it work temporarily.  If that is the case wiring is anyone’s guess and I would have to physically trace each wire and verify if it is the same as the wiring diagram. It is possible that one or more of the wires in the cable going from the thermostat I the furnace are broken. Since you have never needed the blue wire until now you may have never noticed it. Using a multi meter at the thermostat you should get 24 volts between the R and C terminals.

Comment: I see the blue connected to C and it's disconnected at the thermostat because no power to thermostat with blue.  The nest E don't detects power.  I have red and white connected in thermostat but they are connected where the tech made that change in the furnace not in the R and W connectors.  The green is in G in both sides and yellow is in Y in both sides..  should I use brown for C and test? Maybe color blue is broken or something.i have to test with a multimeter when back.

Comment: Problem solved.  Replaced bad part from board and removed temporary fix from tech.  Nest is now ok.  Thanks!